# Copy values from multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba, copy, copy-paste

All I need to do is copy values from different rows, say row A40:D40, A47:D47 etc. 
I have the code that runs properly for one row at a time, but when I try to do two different rows say A40:D40 and A47:D47 it will copy A40:D40 & A41:D41.

```
Sub LoopCopyValues()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim FilePath As String


FilePath = "C:\Users\"
MyFile = Dir(FilePath)

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    If MyFile = "Master Macro.xlsm" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Workbooks.Open (FilePath & MyFile)

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("A2) Monthly P&L (Source)").Activate

Range("CZ447:DC447").Copy

ActiveWorkbook.Close False

Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

ActiveSheet.Paste

MyFile = Dir
```

Loop

End Sub

Comment: Your current code copy only one row, how did you try to copy two rows. Please not that you can't do multiple selection in VBA like you do it manually.

Comment: @MátéJuhász can't do multiple selection? Haven't you ever used `Union()` or `Range("A1, B4, D5:D23").Copy` ?

Comment: Yes your right. I've missed with word VBA.

Answer (score 1):

If you're always selecting the same set of rows you can hard code it like below.

```
Range("A8:D9,A12:D13,A16:D17").Select
Selection.Copy
```

Alternatively if your ranges very then you can set up a relative string and then use the same method.

```
rw1 = Range("a50000").End(xlUp).Row
clm1 = Range("a50000").End(xlToLeft).Column
rng1 = "a1:" & Cells(rw1, clm1).Address(False, False)

rw2 = Range("a50000").End(xlUp).Row
clm2 = Range("a50000").End(xlToLeft).Column
'may being whatever your critera is for finding a reference cell
fnd2 = Cells.Find(What:="may", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Address

rng2 = fnd2 & ":" & Cells(rw1, clm1).Address(False, False)
rng1 = rng1 & "," & rng2

Range(rng1).Select
Selection.Copy
```

Comment: I see why it didn't work.  modify to the below.


rng1 = rng1 & "," & rng2

Range(rng1).Select
Selection.Copy

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Range("A40:D40, A47:D47").Copy
```

Another way of doing this without using `.Select`:

```
Sub LoopCopyValues()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim FilePath As String
Dim ws1 As Excel.Worksheet, wb2 As Excel.Workbook

Set ws1 = ActiveWorksheet

FilePath = "C:\Users\"
MyFile = Dir(FilePath)

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0    
    If MyFile = "Master Macro.xlsm" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(FilePath & MyFile)
        Range("CZ447:DC447").Copy Destination:= _
            ws1.Range("B" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

        wb2.Close False

        MyFile = Dir
    End If
Loop

Set ws1 = Nothing
Set wb2 = Nothing

End Sub
```